# Rails + Devise: Custom login failure flash messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to show a flash alert for when users fail to sign in. However, there will be two different cases:

1. The email entered by the user exists, but the password is wrong. I want this message to show: `The email address or password you entered is incorrect.`
2. The email entered by the user doesn't exist. I want this message to show: `The email address and password you entered do not match our records. (You provided <span class='black'>#{params[:email]}</span>)<br/><br/>
       <a href='/accounts/forgot_password' class='decorate'>Having trouble accessing your account?</a>`

Is there a hook similar to the `after_sign_in_path` where I can modify the flash based on these conditions?

**UPDATE**

So I found this. But how do I pass in the email variable ONLY for `not_found_in_database`?

```
en:
  devise:
    failure:
      already_authenticated: "You are already signed in."
      invalid: "The email address or password you entered is incorrect."
      not_found_in_database: "The email address and password you entered do not match our records. (You provided <span class='black'>%{email}</span>)<br/><br/><a href='/accounts/forgot_password' class='decorate'>Having trouble accessing your account?</a>."
```

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. Initialially failure.invalid and failure.not_found_in_database has the same message (so I see same failure message on sign in page), that made me think Devise does not differentiate between these two cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually used this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations

And this:

```
                <% if !flash[:alert].blank? %>
                    <% if flash[:alert][/The email address and password you entered do not match our records/] %>
                        <div class="flashNotice col last">
                            <%= t('devise.failure.not_found_in_database', resource_name: "#{params[:user][:email]}").html_safe %>
                        </div>
                    <% else %>
                    <!-- Style for any warning message -->
                        <div class="flashNotice col last"><%= flash[:alert]%></div>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
```

Comment: could you separete the message from password and email .. so its a different message for both?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend you to differenciate these two cases. It is possible to mine email addresses from your page if you give this information. They only need to bombard your system with random addresses and dummy passwords, and they eventually will find some valid emails. If it is a small page it doesn't matter much, but it's better to avoid the problem.

Comment: Generally, Devise by default leaks this information during account creation (it prevents duplicate email addresses from signing up), even in paranoid mode. It's just as possible to mine email addresses from the signup form. So you're not really losing any real security by doing this unless you've also stopped that leak.